# How can I do ModelBinding with HttpTrigger in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, model-binding

I need to create an Azure Function that responds to a HTTP POST, and leverages the integrated model binding.

How can I modify this

```
    [FunctionName("TokenPolicy")]
    public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "TokenPolicy/{IssuerID}/{SpecificationID}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string IssuerID, string specificationID, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. TokenPolicy");

        // Fetching the name from the path parameter in the request URL
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "data " +  specificationID);
    }
```

in such a way that my client POST's the object, and I have normal ASP.NET style model binding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using an `HttpRequestMessage` parameter, you can use a custom type. The binding will attempt to parse the request body as JSON and populate that object before calling the function. Some details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#payload

Answer (score 13):

Based on the documentation from [HTTP trigger from code](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#payload), you can simply accept your own object:

> For a custom type (such as a POCO), Functions will attempt to parse
> the request body as JSON to populate the object properties.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[FunctionName("TokenPolicy")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "TokenPolicy/{IssuerID}/{SpecificationID}")]MyModel myObj, string IssuerID, string specificationID, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. TokenPolicy");


    // Do something your your object

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: How do I return a result... req is gone req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "data " +  specificationID);

Comment: Thanks, but what is the alternative to    HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK); if I need to send JSON?

Comment: I assume that if you do this, you no longer have access to the HttpRequestMessage object to get things like client ip address.